# How to install Microsoft.Office.Interop references in VS.NET 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

I was trying to create a windows forms using the Microsoft.Office.Interop libraries, but I cannot find them. I tried to follow the guides only and installed the Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable, but the references did not show up in the COM tab. I closed VS.NET, restarted my computer and they still did not show.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIA is just an interop layer, you need Office installed to see a COM reference. If you reference a COM type library, AND a corresponding PIA is installed correctly, your reference will be replaced by a PIA one. You can also reference the PIA directly by browsing to its folder and add reference, but the PIA won't be functional unless you have Office installed.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was under the idea that it would work without Office. Thank you very much.